# Flutter expand Row inside ListView

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to use a `Row` inside a horizontally scrolling list. When there are only few children in the row, the row should take up the full with and apply `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` such that it looks like this:

[image]

However when there are a lot of items, such that it doesn't fully fit on the screen, the row should be scrollable.

I currently have this code:

```
    Container(
      height: 40,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 40,
                color: Colors.red
              ),
              Container(
                width: 100,
                height: 40,
                color: Colors.blue
              ),
              
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
```

However the Row's width is only as wide as the children's combined with, such that it doesn't apply `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`. So it looks like this:

[image]

Is there a good way to achieve this in Flutter? So I need to expand the Row to atlest the full ListView with but also allow it to go larger.

Comment: Use a [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) to calculate if there is enough room to fit without scrolling and space out the elements of the Row. If there isn't, then use the `ListView`.

Comment: @ChristopherMoore the problem is, I don't know the width of the children, the code above is just a simplification of what I'm trying to do, so I don't think there is a way to calculate the combined with of the children

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use a `LayoutBuilder` to understand the constraints of our viewport.
Inside we can return a `SingleChildScrollView` to apply the scrolling effects.
Now we want the minimum width of our row to be the same as the maximum amount of width we have, here we can use a `ConstrainedBox` to add an extra `minWidth` constraint to our row:

```
LayoutBuilder(
  builder: (BuildContext context, BoxConstraints viewportConstraints) {
    return SingleChildScrollView(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      child: ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints(
          minWidth: viewportConstraints.maxWidth,
        ),
        child: Row(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Container(width: 100, height: 40, color: Colors.red),
            Container(width: 100, height: 40, color: Colors.blue),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  },
),
```

Notice how we're using `MainAxisSize.min` because we want the row to use as little width as it can but it's constrained by the `minWidth` we provided to the `ConstrainedBox`.

Result:

[image: before]

When they don't fit:

[image: after]

Comment: Thank you, this is a very nice solution. By now I came up with something my self but this is much better!